# how to use golang mongodb driver query $or with $and?

Tags: go, mongo-go-driver

1.judge field `label_status` is exists, if exists is true find one record.
2.if field `label_status` exist is false. find one record `label_status`  eq 1 and `author`
eq `sample`

i use the code:

```
bson.D{
        {"$or", bson.D{{"label_status", bson.D{{"$exists", false}}}}},
        {"$and", bson.A{bson.M{"label_status": Labeling}, bson.M{"annotator": "sample"}}},
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
err := collection.FindOne(context.Background(), bson.D{
        {"$or", bson.D{{"label_status", bson.D{{"$exists", false}}}}},
        {"$and", bson.A{bson.M{"label_status": Labeling}, bson.M{"annotator": "sample"}}},
    }).Decode(&result)
```